# Calling sendFollowerNotification Firebase Function from Android App

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I realize that, since version 12.0, you can call Firebase Functions directly from an Android app... this makes sense with the given example for sending messages:

```
private Task<String> addMessage(String text) {
        // Create the arguments to the callable function.
        Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put("text", text);
        data.put("push", true);

        return mFunctions
                .getHttpsCallable("addMessage")
                .call(data)
                .continueWith(new Continuation<HttpsCallableResult, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String then(@NonNull Task<HttpsCallableResult> task) throws Exception {
                        // This continuation runs on either success or failure, but if the task
                        // has failed then getResult() will throw an Exception which will be
                        // propagated down.
                        String result = (String) task.getResult().getData();
                        return result;
                    }
                });
    }
```

...where you're sending text to a function.

```
exports.addMessage = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  // [START_EXCLUDE]
  // [START readMessageData]
  // Message text passed from the client.
  const text = data.text;
  // [END readMessageData]
  // [START messageHttpsErrors]
  // Checking attribute.
  if (!(typeof text === 'string') || text.length === 0) {
    // Throwing an HttpsError so that the client gets the error details.
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument', 'The function must be called with ' +
        'one arguments "text" containing the message text to add.');
  }
  // Checking that the user is authenticated.
  if (!context.auth) {
    // Throwing an HttpsError so that the client gets the error details.
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('failed-precondition', 'The function must be called ' +
        'while authenticated.');
  }
```

But I'm not exactly sure what I should be sending for something like the sendFollowerNotification example:

https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications

```
exports.sendFollowerNotification = functions.database.ref('/followers/{followedUid}/{followerUid}')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {
      const followerUid = context.params.followerUid;
      const followedUid = context.params.followedUid;
      // If un-follow we exit the function.
      if (!change.after.val()) {
        return console.log('User ', followerUid, 'un-followed user', followedUid);
      }
```

I mean... assuming the users are logged-in and have firebase UIDs and are in the database (my app automatically creates a firebase user when someone logs in)... it would appear that sendFollowerNotification just gets everything from the realtime database.

So what do I  put under?:

```
.call(data)
```

And how am I retrieving the UID for the user that I'm trying to follow? For one that's logged in and using the app... I obviously already have that user's UID, token, and everything else... but I'm unsure of how to retrieve that info for the user who's about to be followed... if that makes any sense.

I've googled all over the internet and have never found an example of this particular kind of function call being used from within an android app using the new post 12.0.0 method. So I'm curious to know what the proper syntax should be.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  You have a callable trigger and a database trigger.  They do different things and don't seem to be directly related.  I don't see why the work of one would change the work of the other.

Comment: @DougStevenson Hahaha! That IS the question. I *know* they're not related. Which means I don't have an example of how to do a database trigger from Android. I don't know how to do it. This is my first time working with Firebase Functions. I have a perfect example of how to do a callable trigger... and I have NO example of how to do a database trigger.

Comment: You have documentation, and a truckload of samples from the functions-samples repo.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events

Comment: You're still not understanding me... I know how functions work... just not how to call them from Android. I already got the sendFollowerNotification example to work... in HTML. From like a web browser. I'm just not sure how to call it from Android. That's the whole question: How would I write the call from android. I haven't seen any examples of THAT anywhere. That's why I included the "addMessage" example. I know how I would do something like that... in Android... but I don't know how to do sendFollowerNotification... in Android.

Comment: You don't "call" a database trigger from Android, or any client for that matter.  You simply write to the database, and it triggers in response to the write.

Comment: You are exactly right, Doug. And I created a function to write to the database but I'm not sure how to launch that function from Android. That's what I need help doing, Doug. If you can put something in the form of an answer for how I might do that... I would gladly accept it.

Comment: I think you'd be helped by the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Comment: "You don't "call" a database trigger from Android, or any client for that matter. You simply write to the database, and it triggers in response to the write. " It was exactly as you said in the end. My apologies for taking so long to grasp it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok! This one really enraged me trying to figure it out... It turns out you don't need to call "sendFollowerNotification" at all.. All it does is it **listens for changes to the Firebase Realtime Database**. If you make changes in the syntax where sendFollowerNotification is looking... it automatically sends out the notification.

There's no call at all in "sendFollwerNotification" for writing users to the Realtime Database. I actually handle this at login:

```
private DatabaseReference mDatabase; //up top

mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(); //somewhere in "onCreate"

final String userId = mAuth.getUid();

String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).child("displayName").setValue(name);
mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).child("notificationTokens").child(refreshedToken).setValue(true);
mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).child("photoURL").setValue(avatar);
```

Then when one user follows another I just write that to the realtime database as well:

```
mDatabase.child("followers").child(user_Id).child(follower_id).setValue(true);
```

And that's it! The second a new follower is added to the RealTime Database... sendFollwerNotification will automatically send out a notification. You just need to setup a listener in your app for receiving messages and where it should redirect your users once they tap a message that's been received and you're done.